# Submit input text using HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I am trying to see inputed texting using HTML and PHP.
From what I have written so far, I am trying to display a name and email after running through PHP, but the only thing shown is:

```
Welcome 
Your email address is:
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: 
<?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>



</body>
</html>
```

How can I make it so I see the input submitted?

Comment: Are you running this from your own machine or hosted? If local machine; is PHP/webserver installed and running correctly? If not; there's your problem.

Comment: You say "when I run it" - what does that mean? Via your browser? Loading what page? Putting what into the address bar?

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 2... so I just press "open in browser" ... but I also did it in a notepad and double click the html file....

Comment: @Valentina No, this will not work. In order to make it work you need to install a web-server and PHP parser. Or simple google for `EasyPHP`, that contains it all

Comment: unbelievable! ... sorry for the question, but it's my first time with php and i didn't know that... :/  ... i shall download it and see how it works...  THX!